# Run-time error in VBA on pasting from excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have some fairly straightforward VBA code to copy either 1 or 2 rows at a time from Excel onto successive PowerPoint slides.

When I run it line for line in debug mode, the code works perfectly. However, when I run it without stepping trhough it manually, I get an error very early in the while-loop (**usually around the 2nd or 3rd iteration**).

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonExportToPowerPoint_Click()


Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

Dim lFirstRow As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim sRangeString As String

Dim lNumberOfPptSlidesToAdd As Long

lFirstRow = 84
lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lNumberOfPptSlidesToAdd = (lLastRow - lFirstRow) / 2

sRangeString = "B" & lFirstRow & ":B" & lLastRow & ",L" & lFirstRow & ":L" & lLastRow & ",M" & lFirstRow & ":M" & lLastRow & ",N" & lFirstRow & ":N" & lLastRow

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(sRangeString)
rng.Select

On Error Resume Next


Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")


Err.Clear


If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")


If Err.Number = 429 Then
MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate


Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("C:\some\path\to\existingppt\test.pptx")
rng.Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Dim lCurrentFirstRowToCopy As Long
lCurrentFirstRowToCopy = 2 + 1

lLastRow = lLastRow - lFirstRow + 1

Dim lPowerPointCurrentSlide As Long
lPowerPointCurrentSlide = 18

Dim sFirstRowValue, sSecondRowValue As String



While lCurrentFirstRowToCopy <= lLastRow

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy).MergeCells = True Then
        MsgBox ("Cell E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy & " is merged: " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy).MergeCells)
    End If

    sFirstRowValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy).Value
    sSecondRowValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy + 1).Value
    If Left(sFirstRowValue, 5) = Left(sSecondRowValue, 5) Then
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy & ":H" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy + 1)
        lCurrentFirstRowToCopy = lCurrentFirstRowToCopy + 2
    Else
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy & ":H" & lCurrentFirstRowToCopy)
        lCurrentFirstRowToCopy = lCurrentFirstRowToCopy + 1
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    rng.Copy
    myPresentation.Slides(lPowerPointCurrentSlide).Select
    PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Paste"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    lPowerPointCurrentSlide = lPowerPointCurrentSlide + 1

Wend


rng.Clear





End Sub
```

As mentioned, when running the code "live", i.e. not stepping through it, the code always fails on **either** line

```
myPresentation.Slides(lPowerPointCurrentSlide).Select
```

or line

```
PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Paste"
```

The error I get is usually this one: [Run-time error -2147023170: Automation Error: The remote procedure call failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6fsE.png)

However, sometimes I also get Run-time error 462 or even Run-time error -2147467259 (Method 'ExecuteMso' of object '_CommandBars' failed.

The fact that it works when stepping through the code makes me think it may have  something to do with timing / process priorities, but adding Application.Wait statements to wait 10 seconds did not fix this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

My recollection is that the `ExecuteMso` and/or Paste operation is asynchronous, so what often happens is that it hasn't finished *pasting* by the time it gets to the next iteration. I'm not 100% sure this will solve the problem but I would try something like this, to hopefully ensure the paste is completed before continuing the loop.

```
Dim numShapes as Long ' get the current number of shapes on the slide
Dim sld as PowerPoint.Slide
Set sld = myPresentation.Slides(lPowerPointCurrentSlide)
sld.Select
numShapes = sld.Shapes.Count
PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Paste"
While sld.Shapes.Count < numShapes + 1
    DoEvents
Wend
lPowerPointCurrentSlide = lPowerPointCurrentSlide + 1
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks. I implemented your method and it works sometimes, but not always. I want to start pasting at slide 18, so before the loop, I set lPowerPointCurrentSlide to 18. About 70% of the time, the macro works, chugging away, pasting the correct information from slide 18 onwards (18,19,20, etc), until the loop terminates correctly...

Comment: ...However, the other ca. 30% of the time, the macro somehow disregards that I want to start at slide 18. Instead it starts at slide 1, copies the information I wanted on slide 18 to slide 1, and then doesn’t continue, just exiting the macro (without any crash or anything similar). So, to sum it up, 70% of the time I end up with the result I want (distinct information copied correctly to slides 18,19,20... etc), and the other 30% of the time I end with only the information that is supposed to be on slide 18, this information however being located on slide 1 for some reason.... any ideas?

Comment: nope. you need to step through the code using some breakpoints & F8 key to step through & see what's happening internally. not something I can debug without your files.

Answer (score 2):

As David has pointed out, this is a timing problem. Here's how I solve this kind of issue. First make a Sleep declaration:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
```

Then add error-checking to the problem line:

```
TryPaste1:
  On Error GoTo TooFastPaste1
  .InsertAfter(vbCr).PasteSpecial msoClipboardFormatPlainText
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Then, after an Exit Sub statement, add the Sleep statement:

```
TooFastPaste1:
  Sleep 10
  Resume TryPaste1
```

This will retry the paste operation at 10 millisecond intervals until it finally succeeds.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your help. Could you elaborate this a bit more? Where does the Exit Sub statement you mention go? and where do I put the TooFastPaste1 block? I have tried implementing this as per your suggestion, but on execution of Resume TryPaste1 I get Run-time error '20': Resume without error.

Comment: When a Sub includes error trapping, you normally put the error coding at the bottom with an Exit Sub just before it so that normal processing of the Sub lets the code quit rather than run through all the error coding. The TooPastePaste1 block goes immediately after the Exit Sub statement. The run-time error is complaining that you didn't include an Exit Sub statement, so execution ran through the error handling when there wasn't any error.